# How do I put content on second line in .txt file and read it

Tags: php, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

For storing values in a `.txt` file I use this code:

```
file_put_contents('data/vote_result.txt', implode(',', $results));
```

and for reading i use this:

```
$results = explode(',', file_get_contents('data/vote_result.txt'));
```

The content of `vote_result.txt` looks like this: `0,1,2,3`

How can I store a second line in the same `.txt` file so that the content looks like this:

```
0,1,2,3
0,1,2,3
```

and how can I read that second line?

Comment: you should really use a data base for this

Answer (score 1):

**Read second line:**

```
$myFile = "data/vote_result.txt";
$linesArray = file($myFile);
echo $linesArray[1]; //line 2
```

If you want to append a line to file, use **FILE_APPEND** flag in  file_put_contents and concatenate "\n" with implode.

```
file_put_contents('data/vote_result.txt', implode(',', $results)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides that you should use a database like MySQL for this, you can use the [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function. Example:

```
$data = file('file.txt');
print $data[1]; // printing out the second line
```

This given you can simply add new lines just by adding a new entry in the array and then implode it with the newline character and save it via the file_put_contents function.

```
$content = implode("\n", $data);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $content);
```